# How to group "remaining" results beyond Top N into "Others" with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When group a pandas dataframe by one column say "version" and which has 10 distinct versions. How can one plot the Top 3 (which cover over 90%) and put the small remainders into one "Other"-Bucket.

```
data = array([
              ('Top1', 14),
              ('Top1', 3),
              ('Top1', 2),
              ('Top2', 6),
              ('Top2', 7),
              ('Other1', 1),
              ('Other2', 2),
         ], 
      dtype=[('Version', 'S10'),('Value', '<i4')])
df = DataFrame.from_records(data)
df.groupby('Version').sum()
```

This returns:

```
Value
Version 
Other1   1
Other2   2
Top1     19
Top2     13
```

Im Looking for

```
Value
Version 
Others   
Top1     19
Top2     13
```

The version names Other* and Top* are just chosen for the example.

Of course this is possible by manually setting the category to "Other" after grouping and comparing to a threshold. I was hoping for a shortcut.

Comment: simple example with input and output dataframes could make it' much easier to work on solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you also want the `Other` group to be summed, for your example to a total of 3?

If i was aiming to win the Pandas one-liner competition this would be my entry:

```
df.replace(df.groupby('Version').sum().sort('Value', ascending=False).index[2:], 'Other').groupby('Version').sum()

         Value
Version       
Other        3
Top1        19
Top2        13
```

But that's completely unreadable, so lets break it down:

You already showed how to sum each group, sorting this result and selecting anything outside of the top 2 can be done with:

```
not_top2 = df.groupby('Version').sum().sort('Value', ascending=False).index[2:]
```

In this example `not_top2` contains `Other1` and `Other2`.

We can replace those `Versions` to a common name with:

```
dfnew  = df.replace(not_top2, 'Other')
print dfnew

  Version  Value
0    Top1     14
1    Top1      3
2    Top1      2
3    Top2      6
4    Top2      7
5   Other      1
6   Other      2
```

The above replaces the contents of `not_top2` in any column. A little substep is needed if you expect this value to occur in any other column than `Version`.

Whats left is to do your original grouping again:

```
dfnew.groupby('Version').sum()
```

Which gives:

```
         Value
Version       
Other        3
Top1        19
Top2        13
```

Comment: here's an open issue to do basically this : https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3960, welcome PR's for it!

Comment: That's a very concise way to do what I meant with manually. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```py
# number of top-n you want
n = 2

# group by & sort descending
df_sorted = (df
                .groupby('Version').sum()
                .sort_values('Value', ascending=False)
                .reset_index()
            )

# rename rows other than top-n to 'Others'
df_sorted.loc[df_sorted.index >= n, 'Version'] = 'Others'

# re-group by again
df_sorted.groupby('Version').sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using value counts instead of GroupBy.

```
# get top 3 versions (also keep the nan values)
versions_to_keep = df['Version'].value_counts(dropna=False)[:3].index

# set all other versions outside of top 3 versions as 'other'
df.loc[~df['Version'].isin(versions_to_keep)]['Version'] = 'Other'
```