# Pandas reduce number of categorical variables in value_counts() tabulation

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, binning

New to pandas I want to perform something similar to [Reduce number of levels for large categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066382/reduce-number-of-levels-for-large-categorical-variables?noredirect=1#comment65482577_39066382) (binning of categorical variables in order to reduce their levels)
The following code works fine in R

```
DTsetlvls <- function(x, newl)  
   setattr(x, "levels", c(setdiff(levels(x), newl), rep("other", length(newl))))
```

My dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Color': 'Red Red Blue'.split(),
                   'Value': [100, 150, 50]})

df['Counts'] = df.groupby('Color')['Value'].transform('count')
print (df)

  Color  Value  Counts
0   Red    100       2
1   Red    150       2
2  Blue     50       1
```

I manually would create an aggregate column and then based on that, label the less frequent groups e.g. "blue" as a single "other" group.
But compared to the concise R code this seems clumsy. What would be the right approach here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to group "remaining" results beyond Top N into "Others" with pandas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835746/how-to-group-remaining-results-beyond-top-n-into-others-with-pandas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), where is condition with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html).

If your variable is of type object see below. If your variable is of type category, then skip down toward the bottom.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Color':'Red Red Blue Red Violet Blue'.split(), 
                   'Value':[11,150,50,30,10,40]})
print (df)
    Color  Value
0     Red     11
1     Red    150
2    Blue     50
3     Red     30
4  Violet     10
5    Blue     40

a = df.Color.value_counts()
print (a)
Red       3
Blue      2
Violet    1
Name: Color, dtype: int64

#get top 2 values of index
vals = a[:2].index
print (vals)
Index(['Red', 'Blue'], dtype='object')
```

---

```
df['new'] = np.where(df.Color.isin(vals), 0,1)
print (df)
    Color  Value  new
0     Red     11    0
1     Red    150    0
2    Blue     50    0
3     Red     30    0
4  Violet     10    1
5    Blue     40    0
```

Or if need replace all not top values use [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['new1'] = df.Color.where(df.Color.isin(vals), 'other')
print (df)
    Color  Value   new1
0     Red     11    Red
1     Red    150    Red
2    Blue     50   Blue
3     Red     30    Red
4  Violet     10  other
5    Blue     40   Blue
```

---

For category type:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Color':'Red Red Blue Red Violet Blue'.split(), 
                   'Value':[11,150,50,30,10,40]})
df.Color = df.Color.astype('category')

a= df.Color.value_counts()[:2].index
print(a)
CategoricalIndex(['Red', 'Blue'], 
                categories=['Blue', 'Red', 'Violet'], 
                ordered=False, dtype='category')
```

Notice that violet is still a category. So we need [`.remove_unused_categories()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalIndex.remove_unused_categories.html).

```
vals = df.Color.value_counts()[:2].index.remove_unused_categories()
CategoricalIndex(['Red', 'Blue'], 
                 categories=['Blue', 'Red'], 
                 ordered=False, dtype='category')
```

As mentioned in the comments, a ValueError will occur when setting the new variable. The way around that is type changing.

```
df['new1'] = df.Color.astype('object').where(df.Color.isin(vals), 'other')
df['new1'] = df['new1'].astype('category')
```

Comment: I get this error `ValueError: Cannot setitem on a Categorical with a new category, set the categories first`. This is due to my variable being categorical already. My fix was adding `.astype('object')` like this `df.Color.astype('object').where(df.Color.isin(vals), 'other')`.